# UITableView with prototype doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I really don't see why is it not scrolling with finger. I'm not using simulator, it's a real device

Here are screenshots from storyboard :

[image]

also, it has user interaction checked

also, I have connection to my VC in dataSource and delegate.
The tableView has outlet as lvMain :

[image]

Here is the code : I add results each second so tableView is populated one by one :

```
var answers = [Answer]()
var shownAnswers = [Answer]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = res.getColor("bg_title")
    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    Utils.AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait)
    initButtons()
    lvMain.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: lvMain)
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self,   selector: (#selector(nextAnswer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


func nextAnswer(){
    shownAnswers.append(answers[arrayIndex])
    arrayIndex += 1
    lvMain.reloadData()
    lvMain.layoutIfNeeded()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: shownAnswers.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.lvMain.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
    if arrayIndex == answers.count {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

So, the tableView is populated fine, but it doesn't scroll. I tried not to populate 1 by 1 , it didn't help.

Not any view is blocking it - you may see it by hierarchy on a screenshot.
Please, make me some advise

Comment: What is this for: self.view.bringSubview(toFront: lvMain)? Maybe it's blocking the user interaction with the table view. Also, you say you're updating it every second. Did you try to disable the update to see if that's the problem?

Comment: @u84six yes, I mentioned it - I tried not to update, the whole list at once - it still didn't scroll.  self.view.bringSubview(toFront: lvMain) is an attempt to solve this issue as there was a solution to non-scrollable tableView I've read on SO. But it doesn't help

Comment: Does your timer invalidates or does it keep running? It might be due the the frequent firing of the timer.

Comment: @HAK it's in the code above, it's 1 per second and invalidates

Comment: Try run scrollToRow in main thread.